# How to create xamarin PCL Project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am not having option for PCL Project while Creating new xamarin project in VS 2019.

I am getting option as shown in image

[image]

I run old PCL Project, It is running successfully.

Please help me to create PCL Project in VS 2019.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Portable Class Libraries (PCLs)** are **deprecated** in the latest versions of Visual Studio.
- you can still open, edit, and compile PCLs
- For new projects it is recommended to use **.NET Standard libraries** to
  access a larger API surface area.

For more details please refer below link:
[PCL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/pcl?tabs=macos)