# Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build in Xamarin.Forms (.Net Standard) Not compatible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I'm creating a Xamaring Forms App and I was using a tutorial where they used Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build. The project was created in Visual Studio 2017 using "Cross platform App".
I'm using visual studio 2019, and I did not find "Cross platform App" so I'm doing my app with Xamarin.Forms Mobile App.

The point is that one uses .NetFramework and the other uses .NetStandard so Microsoft.Bcl and Microsoft.Bcl.Build  are not compatible.

My questions are:

1. Is it ok to build my app using Xamarin.Forms Mobile App? Or is there any way to do like the video?
2. If there isn't option, how could I import those libraries or aren't they necessary?

Thanks

Comment: You could install them in Xamarin.Forms project . In VS 2017 it called Cross platform App .

Comment: I can, but the console sends me athe error that says it's not compatible and it's just for. NetFramework

Comment: I also tried to install VS 2017, but it there are some files that can't be downloaded and when I open it, it doesn't show me any kind of project.

Comment: What's the version of the VS on your pc? I installed the two packages sucessfully on VS 2019 16.7.1. The Microsoft.Bcl package is used with NetFramework, the new version of VS 2019 has introduced the .NetFramework libraries. Try updating your vs to the lastest statable version and test again. Check the links:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/pcl_known_issues/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105978/how-to-create-xamarin-pcl-project-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: I have already updated The problem is that Mobile App in Xamarin Forms uses .NetStandard and it shows me a message that says the package's just for .NetFramework

Comment: Update the IDE to 2019

Comment: I've done that.

Comment: No results seen

Comment: You could post the issue to  **Help->Send Feedback ->Report a problem**  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not needed to install it because it is preloaded in the project, so you can use it whenever you want without installing it.

I used these libraries and it worked perfectly.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net; using System.Net.Http; using
System.Net.Http.Headers;
```